# Как прописать настройки spec файла для конвертации .exe вложенных файлов и папок?

Tags: python, json, exe, path

Я использую в своей программе файлы `.json` для удобного хранения данных. Структура программы вполне примитивна: в каталоге `Main` лежит главный скрипт `Main.py`, который должен создавать файл `inputs.json` в подкаталоге `Main\Calculations`.

А потом в этом подкаталоге скрипт `Calculations.py` обращается к файлу `inputs.json` чтобы работать с ним далее. В IDE PyCharm для работы достаточно прописать относительный путь `Calculations\inputs.json` чтобы программа поняла куда сохранять файл.

Однако если программу залить в `.exe` с помощью **pyinstaller**, то естественно уже не работает такой подход.

Я пробовал вставлять функцию `os.path.abspath()` чтобы получить абсолютный путь, но это не работает. В любом случае выходит ошибка `no such file or directory`

Структура проекта:

```
/Calculations
  |----__init__.py
  |----inputs.json (изначально отсутствует)
  |----Calculations.py
 Main.py
```

Если это важно, то `.json` формируется из таблицы `pandas DataFrame` под названием `mech_df`. Ещё я пробовал использовать функцию `getcwd()` и добавлять к ней подкаталог:

```
main_path = os.getcwd()
inputs_path = os.path.join(main_path, 'Calculations', 'inputs.json')
mech_df.to_json(inputs_path, orient = 'index', indent = 5)
```

**UPD:** В общем, разобравшись я понял, что дело здесь вообще не в каталоге, дело в том, что в моей программе импортируется только `Calculations.py` безотностильно каталога.

Вопрос: как нужно правильно прописать конфиг `spec` файла, чтобы конечный `.exe` файл мог оперировать вложенными папками и файлами в них?

Comment: во время запуска программы, в консоли загорается ошибка `no such file or directory`

Comment: Мне просто кажется, что проблема не в том, что абсолютный путь указан не верно, а в том что функция `to_json()` не имеет прав доступа для создания файла, но это только кажется

Comment: попробуйте использовать appdirs для создания директории, в которой будете хранить json файл.

Comment: В файле `spec` я прописал путь в строке `datas= [('dir/Calculations', 'Calculations')]`, однако теперь программа не собирается в 1 файл, если в папку со всеми зависимостями

Comment: Я нашёл похожую проблему здесь:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile Может кто из русских знает в чём соль?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл я ответ на свой же вопрос. Действительно, данная проблема уже освещалась [на англоязычном stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile). Проблема решается в 2 действия (при условии что вам нужны файлы подкатолагах в рантайме как мне:

1)В `spec` файле вы должны прописать директорию в которой эти самые файлы лежат или будут лежать:

```
datas = [('C:/full/path/to/folder', 'folder')]
```

2)В скрипте который создаёт/обращается к этим файлам вам нужен метод:

```
import sys
import os
def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)`
```

Далее вы должны определить абсолютный путь к каталогу с помощью этого метода:

```
base_path = resource_path('folder')
```

И чтобы окончательно добраться до файла есть замечательный метод `os.path.join()`

```
inp_path = Path(os.path.join(base_path, "inputs.json"))
```

Теперь вы можете прописывать путь `inp_path` для создания файлов в подкаталогах, и исполняемый файл `.exe` полученный из `pyinstaller` будет работать исправно. Я не берусь объяснять полную механику почему это работает именно так, но как я понял, это из-за того, что `pyinstaller` создаёт временную папку и хранит этот путь в `_MEIPASS`. Таким образом вы точно попадёте на правильный каталог, при условии что загрузили его в пункте 1.

Если в ответе или тексте вопроса присуствует технические ошибки, прошу в комментариях их осветить =)